# Is there a better way to check data loss and mismatched data after flink-cdc streamed all my data from database to data lake?

Tags: python, apache-spark, bigdata, apache-iceberg

I have a mysql database with 10TB data, and I have streamed all the data to s3 using iceberg table format through flink-cdc.

I want to check whether there is data loss, or whether there are mismatched data values.

Currently, I have 2 solution using pyspark.

```
# initialize two table in spark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat_ws, md5

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

table_name = 'target_table'
df_iceberg_table = read_iceberg_table_using_spark(table_name)
df_mysql_table = read_mysql_table_using_spark(table_name)
table_columns = get_table_columns(table_name)
```

The first is to calculate the hash value for every row and compare them to check whether data is the same.

```
df_mysql_table_hash = (
    df_mysql_table
        .select(
            col('id'),
            md5(concat_ws('|', *table_columns)).alias('hash')
        )
)

df_iceberg_table_hash = (
    df_iceberg_table
        .select(
            col('id'),
            md5(concat_ws('|', *table_columns)).alias('hash')
        )
)

df_mysql_table_hash.createOrReplaceTempView('mysql_table_hash')
df_iceberg_table_hash.createOrReplaceTempView('iceberg_table_hash')

df_diff = spark.sql('''
    select 
        d1.id as mysql_id, 
        d2.id as iceberg_id, 
        d1.hash as mysql_hash, 
        d2.hash as iceberg_hash
    from mysql_table_hash d1
    left outer join iceberg_table_hash d2 on d1.id = d2.id
    where false
        or d2.id is null
        or d1.hash <> d2.hash
''')

# save df_diff to some where
```

The second is to use the subtract function in pyspark

```
df_diff = df_mysql_table.subtract(df_iceberg_table)

# save df_diff to some where
```

Which one is better and faster?
Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to `subtract()`, you can also use `exceptAll()` method to find the differences between the two DataFrames. To me, it's especially useful in unit-testing. If the result of `exceptAll()` is an empty DataFrame, it means the two DataFrames are identical. Otherwise, the non-empty DataFrame returned by `exceptAll()` contains the rows that are different between the two DataFrames.

```
# Find the differences between df1 and df2
diff = df1.exceptAll(df2)

# Check if there are any differences
if diff.count() == 0:
    print("DataFrames are identical.")
else:
    print("DataFrames have differences.")
    diff.show()
```

Also note that, `exceptAll()` compares the DataFrames based on both the column values and the row order, while `subtract()` compares the DataFrames based on the column values only, ignoring the row order. If the performance is a critical factor and the row order is not important, using `subtract()` is likely to be more efficient than `exceptAll()`, but with `subtract()`, you cannot detect the duplicated rows, if any.